# Is there another language like javascript?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Is there another language that treats functions like variables, like javascript does?

example:

```
var $ = function(a){return document.getElementById(a);}
```

or:

```
function exec(a,b){return a.apply(window,b);}
```

Comment: PHP (the most recent release) can do this. Try Googling functional programming.

Comment: look at the various functional languages.

Comment: Yes, lots of them. Look into functional languages, if you like this paradigm. Many mixed-paradigm languages are inheriting this concept as well though, even PHP.

Comment: Someone came and downvoted every (correct) answer to this. Want to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only about a [million](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/First-class_functions) of them.  People generally want more out of functions than to be able to pass them as variables and invoke them on arguments, but if that's your standard, even C meets it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually PHP can do such thing as you stated in your first example.

```
$lt = function($arg) {
   return str_replace('<', '&lt;', $arg);
}

$lt("<br />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. C++, C# (as of C++11), most functional languages (LISP, StandardML) and pretty sure more others.

EDIT: Have you tried searching online? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function